# Dafny can't prove equivalence of methods

Tags: dafny

Dafny doens't seem to prove equivalence of two methods without post-conditions. Is this expected?

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/c88u

```
function method pipeline_func(x: int): int{
    x * 2
}

function method program_func(x: int): int {
    x + x
}

method pipeline_with_ensures (x: int) returns (x': int) 
    ensures x' == x*2
{
    x' := x*2;
}

method program_with_ensures (x: int) returns (x': int) 
    ensures x' == x+x
{
    x' := x + x;
}

method pipeline(x: int) returns (x': int)
{
    x' := x * 2;
}

method program(x: int) returns (x': int)
{
    x' := x + x;
}

method Main(x: int) {
    // Simple functions can be directly called from expressions and can easily 
    // be asserted as below.
    assert pipeline_func(x) == program_func(x);

    // Methods needs to be assigned to a variables to be used in another
    // expression.
    var a := pipeline_with_ensures(x);
    var b := program_with_ensures(x);

    // With ensures in both program_with_ensures and pipeline_with_ensures 
    // Dafny can verify a equals to b. Similarly functions and methods could be 
    // asserted together. 
    assert a == b;
    assert a == pipeline_func(x);
    assert b == program_func(x);
    assert a == program_func(x);
    assert b == pipeline_func(x);

    var c := pipeline(x);
    var d := program(x);

    // However, without ensures clause, Dafny can't verify that pipeline and
    // pipeline_with_ensures actually compute the same thing. 
    assert a == c;

    assert c == d;
}
```

I have two methods in Dafny that I don't have much information of
their post condition. The context here is that I am developing a compiler using a program synthesis tool and I'd like to formally verify that my compiled program computes the same value as specification for any arbitrary input. My specifications are written in a C-like language as following.

```
#define ECN_THRESH 20

int counter   = ECN_THRESH;
int last_time = 0;

struct Packet {
  int bytes;
  int time;
  int mark;
};

void func(struct Packet p) {
  // Decrement counter according to drain rate
  counter = counter - (p.time - last_time);
  if (counter < 0) counter = 0;

  // Increment counter
  counter += p.bytes;

  // If we are above the ECN_THRESH, mark
  if (counter > ECN_THRESH) p.mark = 1;

  // Store last time
  last_time = p.time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Dafny performs verification "one method at a time", and will never "look inside" the code of another method.

For more information, please see this [FAQ section](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/wiki/FAQ#my-program-is-correct-but-dafny-says-there-is-a-problem-what-gives) and also the section of the [Guide](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide) called Assertions (search for "forget" to get to the relevant part).